# `tidyr::unnest`: "cant't recycle input" error **ONLY** when using `cols = dplyr::everything()`

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, tibble

Consider the following:

```
library(magrittr)
sapply(c("dplyr", "tibble", "tidyr"), requireNamespace)

mytbl <- structure(
  list(
    A = list(c("A.1", "A.2")),
    B = list(c("B.1", "B.2")),
    C = list("C.1"),
    D = list(c("D.1", "D.2")),
    E = list(c("E.1", "E.2", "E.3"))),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

While `tidyr::unnest` works for every individual column like so:

```
lapply(names(mytbl), function(x) tidyr::unnest(mytbl, cols = x))
```

`unnest`ing fails when trying to operate on all columns using `tidyselect`:

```
mytbl %>% tidyr::unnest(cols = dplyr::everything())
Error in `tidyr::unnest()`:
! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 3.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any pointers? What is going on here and ho do I prevent this?

Comment: The problem is that column `E` has one row with three entries.  The other columns have one row with 1 or 2 entries.  Entries of length 1 can be recycled to  length 2, but entries of length 3 can't.  What do you *want* the output to be?  [Delete column `E` and you get output, but I don't know if it's what you want.]

Comment: Your "working" code gives a list of tibbles with varying numbers of rows.  Your "failing" code attempts to produce a single tibble.  Which do you want? They're fundamentally different outputs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that your columns have different lengths (e.g., A is 2, but C is 1, and E is 3). A `data.frame` object, which is what returns `unnest`, cannot have columns of different lengths.

I'm not aware of an easy solution, but one possibility is to pad NAs to every vector to match the maximum length. This requires pivoting first:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

mytbl %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  mutate(value = map(value, `length<-`, max(lengths(value)))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  A     B     C     D     E    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A.1   B.1   C.1   D.1   E.1  
2 A.2   B.2   NA    D.2   E.2  
3 NA    NA    NA    NA    E.3
```

---

In base R, you can do:

```r
l <- unlist(mytbl, recursive = FALSE)
as.data.frame(lapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l))))
```